# Python Selenium if elif not work when click links

Tags: python, html, selenium, if-statement

I am trying to click all links (and get elements) in a specific date (like today), else quit if it is published (like yesterday).

I use if-elif to achieve it but the website just continue clicking links despite of date, please find my codes here:

Any help will be highly appreciated!

```
dates = [date.get_attribute('innerHTML') for date in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('')]
for date in dates:
     if date == '[01-20]':
        links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('')]
        for link in links:
            driver.get(link)
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text('')
        next_page.click()
     elif date != '[01-20]': 
       driver.close()
```

Comment: Hi actually the link and the date are separate elements, like:  today news    1/21/2020

Comment: Can you post a sample of the web elements you need to grab.

Comment: Did you translate the page in options.

Comment: no , just the original page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to get all href tags with the text of [01-20] to open and go back.

```
driver.get('http://www.csisc.cn/zbscbzw/isinbm/index_list_code.shtml')
while True:
    hrefs=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[text()='[01-20]']/preceding::td[1]/a")]
    for href in hrefs:
        driver.get(href)
        driver.back()
    if(len(hrefs)< 20):
        break
    try:
        #next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//font[text()='Next page']/ancestor::a")
        next_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text("下一页")
        next_page.click()
    except:
        print('No more pages')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much Arundeep! It worked! And what if I just want to click some links contain some words?

Comment: There's about 20 links per page, using a for loop you can driver.find_elements_by_xpath("")[index] for the element to click and then check it's .text value and exit.

Comment: Hi thanks! but I want a bucket of words, like {"","","',...},would you mind helping with my new question post, I explain the question in details. Thank you!